# We want to show 10 tweets in a list using microservice registered on eureka but i am getting 405 error

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, netflix-eureka

```
    index.html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <title>Spring Security Example - ProgrammingFree</title>
    </head>
    <!-- <link href="<spring:url value="css/app.css" /> -->
    <body class="security-app">
        <div class="details">
            <h2>Spring Application HBase Elasticsearch</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="lc-block">
            <h1>Welcome!</h1>

            <div class="alert-normal">

              Click <a href="/es.html">here</a> to see a greeting. 

             <!-- Click<a href="/eshtml" onclick="this.form.submit()">here</a> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    **es.html**

     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!--  <link href="<c:url value="css/app.css" />  -->
      <script type="text/javascript">

        function script(){
        var companyName = document.getElementById('companyName').value;
        var contains = document.getElementById('contains').value;
        var console = document.getElementById('console');
        var esControllerCall="/ess?companyName="+companyName+"&contains="+contains";
        var source = new EventSource(esControllerCall);
        source.onmessage = function (event) {

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var data=event.data;
            //alert(data);
            var dataarray=data.split('tid-');
            //alert(dataarray);
            a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataarray[0]));
            var p = document.createElement('p');

            p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
            p.appendChild(a);
            console.appendChild(p);
            console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;

        };
        }
        </script> 
    <title>ES DATA</title>
    </head>
     <body class="security-app"> 
      <body class="security-app" onsubmit="script();> 
         <div class="details">
            <h2>Spring Application Authentication</h2>
        </div> 

        <div class="lc-block">

            <form action="/ess" method="post">
        <label>Company Name</label> <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName"/></br>
        <label>Contains Word</label>    <input type="text" name="contains" id="contains" /></br>

                <input type="submit" class="button red big" value="Search " /> 
                <!-- <input
                    type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" /> -->
                <div id="console" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>

            </form>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html> 


<!-- end snippet -->

**strong text**

escontroller

package com.microservice;

@RestController
public class ESController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<String> dataFromEs(@RequestParam("companyName") String companyName,
            @RequestParam("contains") String contains)
            throws UnknownHostException {
        Client client;

        client = TransportClient
                .builder()
                .build()
                .addTransportAddress(
                        new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress
                                .getByName("10.10.167.157"), 9300));

        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(companyName)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("text", contains))
                .setSize(200).execute().actionGet();

        System.out.println("response received is: "+response);

        List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits().getHits()) {

            valuesList.add(hit.getSource().get("text").toString());
            valuesList.add(hit.getSource().get("id").toString());
            valuesList.add(hit.getSource().get("epochTime").toString());
        }

        return valuesList;

    }
}
```

---

```
esservice

 package com.microservice;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient 

public class ESService {
            @Autowired
    ESController esController = new ESController();
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ESService.class, args);
    }
}
```

The below is the code for consuming microservice.i.e eureka client or discovery client to get the microservices.and we are unable to implement post method and not able to check it on UI

```
package com.MasterService;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
public class MasterService {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        SpringApplication.run(MasterService.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();

    }

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    private List<String> listofValue;

    private String indexName;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<String> dataFromEs(
            @RequestParam("companyName") String companyName,
            @RequestParam("contains") String contains)
            throws InterruptedException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        ServiceInstance sinstance = this.discoveryClient.getInstances(
                "es-service").get(0);

        URI storesUri = URI.create(String.format("http://%s:%s/dataFromEs/",
                sinstance.getHost(), sinstance.getPort()));

        System.out.println("## " + storesUri.toString() + " ##");

        indexName = companyName;

        System.out.println("indexName----> " + indexName);

        String name = "tweet_" + indexName + "_1467072000_1472256000";

        System.out.println("indexName----> " + name);

        System.out.println("contains----------------->" + contains);

        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        param.put("companyName", companyName);
        param.put("contains", contains);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("companyName", companyName + "");
        map.add("contains", contains + "");

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(storesUri.toString());

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("companyName", companyName
                + ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contains", contains + ""));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(map);

        String stringResult = restTemplate().postForObject(storesUri, map,
                String.class);

        System.out.println("-------- " + stringResult);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Response Code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                .getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer resultBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            resultBuffer.append(line);
        }
        String result = resultBuffer.toString();

        listofValue.add(result);
        // indexName = "tweet_" + companyName + "_1467072000_1472256000";


        return listofValue;
    }
}

**the below is the error that i am trying to solve it.** Please do help us where we are going wrong .
```

We are getting 405 error.(405 Method Not Allowed) exception
Thanks in advance.

```
**org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method Not Allowed**
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at 

I am unable to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Shouldn't `storesUri` be `"http://%s:%s/ess/"` instead of `"http://%s:%s/dataFromEs/"` ?

Comment: Thanks for reply Its working

Comment: I haven't gone through you js part of the code but given the error on your stacktrace, either you are calling the endpoints with HTTP Method GET instead of POST since both your resource declarations are expecting POST, or better yet change your method to GET since you are just returning a list. `RequestMethod.GET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, I think the issue is your `storesUri`, it should be like this:

```
                                                       change this
                                                            |
                                                            v
    URI storesUri = URI.create(String.format("http://%s:%s/ess/",
            sinstance.getHost(), sinstance.getPort()));
```

i.e. replace `dataFromEs` (the method name) by `ess` (the endpoint name)